# Teamcity server on windows server architecture?

Tags: django, ubuntu, teamcity

I have setup TeamCity on a Windows instance and I want to deploy builds on an Ubuntu server (django app).
As a newbie I'm a bit confused how the whole TeamCity architecture works in this scenario?

Do I need to add or define my target Ubuntu machine as a build agent in TeamCity server? If yes then, how am I able to push those builds on to the target Ubuntu server?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible. More informations can be found [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents). Please check the documentation next time first.